# Java Semaphore methods not working as expected

Tags: java, multithreading, deadlock, semaphore

I am new to the consumer producer problem and the Semaphore.
The following code is getting Deadlocked in the condition that Producer thread gets stuck when it is acquiring the permit again just after adding in the queue..

Only this is the case when program is deadlocked.

```
public class UsingSemaphore {

    volatile static boolean check = true;

    public static void main(String args[]) throws InterruptedException {

        Semaphore semCon = new Semaphore(0);

        Semaphore semProd = new Semaphore(1);

        Queue<Integer> q = new LinkedList<>();


        // Producer lambda
        Runnable producer = () -> {
            while (check) {
                try {
                    semProd.acquire();

                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                try {
                    
                    Random rand = new Random();
                    q.add(rand.nextInt(10));    
                }finally {
                    semCon.release();

                }
            }   
        };
                //Consumer lambda
        Runnable consumer = () -> {
            while (check) {
                try {

                    semCon.acquire();

                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                try {
                    System.out.println("Consumer item " + q.remove());
                
                }finally {
                    semProd.release();

                }
            }
        };  
        
        ThreadGroup pg = new ThreadGroup("PG");
        ThreadGroup cg = new ThreadGroup("CG");

        Thread p1 = new Thread(pg, producer, "p1");

        Thread c1 = new Thread(cg, consumer, "c1");


        p1.start();

        c1.start();

        Thread.sleep(10);
        check = false;
    }
}
```

The consumer thread does not run in the test case where producer goes to acquire permit... please somebody help

Comment: Taking a stackdump of the process when it's stuck would be helpful, at a glance I can't see where the deadlock happens (perhaps if one thread dies between the two try stmts?). But generally it's not ideal to use 2 semaphores, one semaphore is meant to protect one resource from getting accessed by a certain number of processes. I'm suspecting that what you want to do would be better done with Lock and Condition (see the example here https://devdocs.io/openjdk~19/java.base/java/util/concurrent/locks/condition)

Comment: Why do you think that there is a deadlock? There is no deadlock when I run your program. The program terminates normally...

Comment: ...After printing _one line of output._ If I change `sleep(10)` to `sleep(100)` then it prints many lines of output. Maybe a ten millisecond sleep is not long enough to allow the threads to get started and do quite as much work as you were expecting them to do.

Comment: @SolomonSlow there is a deadlock... run the program more than once there is a case where the program never ends... stack trace shows it occurs when producer try to acquire the permit at semProd.acquire();

Comment: @SolomonSlow lol after changing to sleep(100), there is a deadlock due to consumer at semCon.acquire()... Maybe the reason is I make the flag "check" after Thread.sleep() as false and the thread waits forever to acquire the permit...

Comment: @nomoa yes its great using lock and condition.. I just wanted to experiment with Semaphore

Comment: if the producer or the consumer never enter the while loop you'll get a deadlock, this is possible if check is set to false before the while loop is reached. You must set the check flag to false only after you are sure that the producer has produced something or that the consumer has effectively entered the loop.

Comment: @nomoa yes you are right but the code is getting stuck at semCon.acquire() as the stacktrace in DEBUG window shows=>Thread [c1] (Running).. plus it is after the while loop has entered.. even the flag is false the permit should be available but it isn't

Comment: Similarly when the loop ends, e.g. right after semProd.release(); if p1 loops twice (first iteration it'll produce, second it'll wait on semProd.acquire()), then check is set to false, c1 exits but p1 remains stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is I think the lack of synchronization around the `check` flag that allows your loop to start or end.

It is possible for instance that the producer starts the loop and waits for `semProd.acquire()` (on its second iteration) but the consumer never actually started because the `check` flag was evaluated to false.

When the loops end, both the consumer and the producer must end at the right time or a deadlock can occur when you consider the sequence of events:

```
C1:   semProd.release()
P1:   semProd.acquire() -> OK
P1:   q.add()
P1:   semCon.release()
P1: while(check) -> IN
P1:   semProd.acquire() -> wait
MAIN: check <- false
C1: while(check) -> OUT
C1: stops
P1: deadlocked
```

Same applies the other way around if C1 is trying to acquire `semCon` .

Answer (score 0):

Extended comment, not an answer.

Nomoa said, "if the producer or the consumer never enter the while loop you'll get a deadlock..."

You replied, "yes you are right but the code is getting stuck at semCon.acquire()"

Sure. Here's how that can happen:

```
Producer          Consumer          Main
--------------    --------------    -----------
                  test flag
                  (it's true)
                                    flag=false
test flag
(it's false)
return
                  semCon.acquire()
```

The `semCon` semaphore was initialized to zero, and no permit is ever released to it. The consumer hangs.

For the producer to hang on startup, it's a little bit tricker, but it can happen like this:

```
Producer           Consumer          Main
--------------     --------------    -----------
test flag
(it's true)
semProd.acquire()
semCon.release()
test flag
(it's true)
                                     flag=false
                   test flag
                   (it's false)
                   return
semProd.acquire()
```

The longer you make the main thread `sleep` before it sets `check=false`, the less likely that either of these two scenarios can happen.

Comment: And you could close the holes by interrupting the threads (and writing proper exception handlers rather than the useless boilerplate ones that just carry on executing) after setting 'check' false.

Comment: @chetansharma, you should accept nomoa's answer instead of this one. I didn't intend it to be an answer. I only was trying to expand on what nomoa said in a comment.